# Why my time is not correct, it is always 12 hours late

Tags: ntp

exact with the minutes but wrong with the hours.
Mon Sep  8 08:54:44 BST 2014.
When actually it is 20:54.
I did : `sudo /etc/init.d/ntp restart`    at least ten times no avail.
My raspi activates a timelapse camera and has been working for month without any problem with the correct time and all of a sudden this problem occured without any intervention.
Now the camera instead of taking a picture at 10:00, take it at 22:00....Too bad it's dark.

Comment: Did you set /etc/localtime according to your timezon. E.g. (on Archlinux) `ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin /etc/localtime` Ok, your date states BST looks like time is already localized. Mmmh.

Comment: IS this Raspian or another distro?

Comment: My distro is Raspbian wheezy. And the timezone is well configured through Raspi-Config. Never seen this kind of problem !

Comment: What is the output of `ntpdate -du pool.ntp.org`

Comment: Is the pi connected to a network via ethernet cable or wifi?  If not, ntpd can't update and the pi has no hardware timeclock.

Comment: If it wouldn't have any network connection it wouldn't be Sept, 8th after all...

Answer (score 2):

Considering that the RPi has got no Real Time Clock and starts at January, 1st, 1970 every reboot, I assume that your `ntp`is working fine. Check with `date -u` the system time in UTC and compare to reality. It's most probably right (unless you used `date -s` to set the time manually).

The guess would be that your timezone settings are wrong. Please check the symbolic link `/etc/localtime` or remove it and create it newly according to your timezone by `ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/<your-timezone-goes-here> /etc/localtime`.

Comment: Note that if you use Raspbian, you can run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` to change easily the timezone.

Comment: Sure. It's noteworthy that the use of configuration tools might overwrite manual settings. (Also a possible error in this case.)

Comment: I did: date -u and the result is:

Comment: and the result is: Mon Sep  8 22:06:10 UTC 2014 when it is really 11:06 ...a real mystery!

Comment: And /etc/timezone, confirms : Europe/London

Comment: What's the content of your `/etc/ntp.conf`?